# Responsive Design Media Queries for Fixed Layout

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I created a website in 1000px width. I want to make it responsive but the media queries doesnt really work.

Is there a way to keep fixed 1000px width but make the website scale down as the browser gets smaller? So far media queries doesnt seem to work.

This is my media queries:

link:

Media queries:

```
@media screen and (max-device-width: 600px) {

.grid_1,
.grid_2,
.grid_3,
.grid_4,
.grid_5,
.grid_6,
.grid_7,
.grid_8,
.grid_9,
.grid_10,
.grid_11,
.grid_12, .container {

    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 2%;
    padding-right: 2%;
    }

    #index, #about, #services, #contact .logo, ul, .slide, .headSub, .aboutContent, .aboutText, 
    .division, .service_buzzwords, .services-content, .serv, .contactPage, .map{
        float: none;
    }
    .nav ul, li, a{
        display: block;
    }
    .division, .aboutImg img{
        display: none;
    }
    .indexContent{
        width: 100%;
    }
    .rw-sentence { font-size: 1em; }
    img{
        width: 70%;
        margin-left: 15%;
        margin-right: 15%;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 320px){
    .rw-sentence { font-size: 0.5em; }
}
```

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: link to the media queries: <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (max-width: 600px)" href="mobile-device.css" />

Comment: Have you added `<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1">` in your `<head>`?

Comment: Yup.. :( I Cant figure out whats wrong.. :(

Answer (score 0):

This is the best way to achieve the desired effect :

- You create a wrapper DIV. You give that wrapper DIV a fixed width (in your case : 1000px) and - in a typical layout - center it.
- Make sure your grid elements inside that wrapper DIV are percentage based. For example, if your first column is supposed to be 400px and your second column is supposed to be 600px, set them at 40% and 60%.
- If you want to support older browsers, you'll need to add an additional child DIV to your grid elements for padding, margin and/or borders. If you don't need to support older browsers, [**border-box**](http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/) should do the trick.
- When your website is smaller than a certain size, use a media query to set the width of the wrapper DIV at 100%.

You can, of course, also use [**a framework that implements this technique**](http://jslegers.github.io/cascadeframework/grid-presentational.html).